# Can "element click intercepted" error in Selenium refer to another window instead of a webElement overlapping?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, webdriverwait, thread-local

I am having tests inconsistently failing because of the following error: "org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (951, 1477)".
I say inconsistently because this only happens if I go overboard with the number of parallel threads (sometimes 4+ is enough to get these errors, sometimes I need 10+ depending on what else I have running at the moment).

As you can see in the error, I am not receiving the second part which you'd usually get if the webElement in question would be obstructed by another webElement, which makes me think that somehow the element can't be clicked because it's hidden by another window... ?
What I mean by the second part is this: "Other element would receive the click: ..." - my errors do not have this part.

The weird part is that my explicit wait (set to 60 seconds) seems to be ignored, which leads me to believe that the wait condition (elementToBeClickable AND visibilityOf) is met, yet the click still doesn't work.
Again, this only happens when running multiple threads in parallel and if they are opened/closed rather slowly because of their high number, which makes the pages take 3-10 seconds to start loading its UI elements.

I am not trying to find the maximum number of threads where I don't get the error, I'm just curious as to why I receive the errors long before the wait timer reaches its end.

I tried multiple tweaks:

- tried different ExpectedConditions (only elementToBeClickable, or only VisibilityOf, or both in conjunction)
- scoured the internet obsessively for an answer
- tried to debug with another person next to me, but to no avail
- filled by code with printlines to understand the order of executions. The only interesting thing I noticed is that the threadLocalDriver.remove() function is called by my Cucumber @After hook (which runs after each scenario) ***before*** my wait condition finishes, i.e.: driver quits and is then removed from threadLocalDriver after the first print, but before the 2nd.

```
public void click(WebElement webElement) {
    System.out.println("starting click on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(waitTimer));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement)).click();
    System.out.println("ending click on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

In fact the "`ending click on thread:...`" string isn't printed at all in the cases where I get that error.

Any idea what conditions I could use to make the program wait until it can actually click on the web element?

Comment: it sounds like the driver is trying to click the element... so it has passed the condition of "element to be clickable" (and it's visible and present in the DOM).  So when the driver tries to click it does a few things... one is to scroll the element into view.  Then it finds the center of the element being clicked and then clicks there.   What's possibly happening is in between the time it finds the coords and then clicks the location has changed or the window is still scrolling.   That time gap would usually be very small, but if you're running low on resources...

Comment: to get around this, you could catch click intercepted exception and re-try...

Comment: Hi @pcalkins, I thought about retrying but somehow convinced myself that I can't do it, didn't think of doing it inside a catch (brilliant!). This fixes my issue, I even checked to see if the try catches anything, and it does; tests still pass though which is perfect.

I will keep the question open for a bit more in case anyone can help me figure out exactly what causes this temporary interception (how can I test if it's really caused by the partial scrolling? what exactly obscures it since the exception message doesn't point to any webElement ?).

Comment: I'm guessing it's not something obscuring it but the coords clicked on can't receive the events for the click (mouseover, mousedown, etc... )  It's the container for the element that will retrieve those events methinks.  It's possible that this element is moving with the scrollbar or that it moves into the visible screen at some point.

Comment: I still don't know what exactly obscures the element, but it indeed has to be scrolled into view. I'll mark the question answered since your suggestion fixed my issue, thank you again.

Comment: Nevermind, can't mark it.